# Redirecting a domain to wordpress on google cloud platform

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I installed WordPress on google cloud platform the first time in my life and besides of a few hick ups I could make it work, but one thing that seems really tricky is pointing a custom domain to WordPress. Here is what I have done so far:

On Google Cloud Platform

1. Created custom zones

[image: See Screenshot]

2. Changed the external ip from ephemeral to static

In Wordpress

1. Changed the WordPress address URL and site address URL to swiftplayground dot io

On Google Domains:

1. Added the custom name servers:

> ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com
>   ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com
>   ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com
>   ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com

2. Added custom resource records:

[image: See Screenshot]

Now if I type 146.148.50.166 into the browser it redirects me to the right domain and website, but nothing happens if I type directly swiftplayground dot io

please help... :(

Comment: It is working fine here, did you wait the DNS propagation time? It usually takes less than 1 hour but it can take 24 hours.  You can check it here https://dnschecker.org/.